On Debian KDE (sddm), how can I switch the audio sink before I login or before a startup sound is played?
For practicality reasons, I leave a detachable headphone cable permanently plugged into the back of my motherboard. My monitor also has speakers though, which I use during the day when I won't disturb anyone who is sleeping by listening to music. In order to be able to quickly switch the audio output / switch between the audio sinks for my monitor, and for my headphones. I have written a quick shell script that detects the current sink, defines the monitor sink and headphone sink as variables, and then switches between them according to what sink was already active.
It works well enough but there are a couple of issues with the script related to my yearning for simpler times...
I have set Windows XP's startup and shutdown sounds to run when I login, and when I shutdown my PC. The problem is though, if I shut down the PC late at night and I want to hear the startup sound the next day when I login, I have to switch the audio sink before powering off. Which means the shutdown sound plays through my monitor's speakers late at night.
So I've been looking for a way of having the audio sink set before I log in, according to what time it is. I've already tried putting the following code in my /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup but it doesn't work for some reason.
# Define the two audio outputs
HEADPHONES="alsa_output.pci-0000_12_00.3.HiFi__hw_Generic__sink" #this is the 
"Line out" headphone output.
MONITOR="alsa_output.pci-0000_0c_00.1.hdmi-stereo" #this is the displayport 
connection to the monitor.

# Decide on the new sink based on the time
if [[ "$current_time" -ge "09:00:00" && "$current_time" -le "23:00:00" ]]; then 
   new_sink="$MONITOR"
else
   new_sink="$HEADPHONES"
fi

# Set the new default sink
pactl set-default-sink "$new_sink"#

Is automatically running a script after I login or when I power off my PC an option?

Your $HOME/.bashrc is a "script that runs at login" (and other times, so look for the use of the $- shell variable) e.g. case "$-" in *i*) echo This shell is interactive ;; *) echo This shell is not interactive ;; esac
